# How to create a custom policy for storage account to deny public access and allow selected networks bypassing the AzureServices?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-storage, azure-policy

**After looking through the policies  I want to merge the policies :**

> - Storage accounts should restrict network access using virtual network    rules Storage accounts
> - should allow access from trusted Microsoft services
> - [Preview]: Storage account public access should be disallowed

But all the three have different effects and are either audit or deny . What I want is to check the storage accounts and for the three rules and then activate those automatically for new resources .

Any Ideas on how to achieve this ? I am using terraform to deploy the policy definitions and remediations .

Comment: you will have to use deployifnotexists effect by defining the policy rules of three in a single policy rule

Comment: let me check and get back here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the below policy which validates the network rules and deny public access for blob is present or not and then deploys it for the new resources :

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
        },
        {
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/networkAcls.defaultAction",
              "notEquals": "Deny"
            },
            {
              "count": {
                "field": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/networkAcls.ipRules[*]"
              },
              "greaterOrEquals": 1
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "not": {
            "field": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/allowBlobPublicAccess",
            "equals": "false"
          }
        }       
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deployIfNotExists",
      "details": {
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
        "name": "[field('name')]",
        "existenceCondition": {
          "field": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/networkAcls.defaultAction",
          "equals": "Deny"
        },
        "roleDefinitionIds": [
          "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/17d1049b-9a84-46fb-8f53-869881c3d3ab"
        ],
        "deployment": {
          "properties": {
            "mode": "incremental",
            "template": {
              "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
              "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
              "parameters": {
                "name": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "sku": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "location": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "kind": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "virtualnetworklist": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "metadata": {
                    "description": "The list of locations that can be specified when deploying resources"
                  },
                  "defaultValue": "test"
                }
              },
              "resources": [
                {
                  "name": "[parameters('name')]",
                  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
                  "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
                  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                  "properties": {
                    "allowBlobPublicAccess": false,
                    "networkAcls": {
                      "bypass": "AzureServices",
                      "defaultAction": "Deny"
                    }
                  },
                  "dependsOn": [],
                  "sku": {
                    "name": "[parameters('sku')]"
                  },
                  "kind": "[parameters('kind')]"
                }
              ]
            },
            "parameters": {
              "name": {
                "value": "[field('name')]"
              },
              "sku": {
                "value": "[field('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/sku.name')]"
              },
              "location": {
                "value": "[field('location')]"
              },
              "kind": {
                "value": "[field('kind')]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: glad to be of help @UserP